# getting a weird error while trying to connect the app.js with mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql

I've installed MongoDB and the compass as well and everything works just fine, when I try to connect mongo with my app.js I get a weird error. Could any of you tell me what the error means and what can I?
Sorry about the links to the images, not allowed to embed images yet..
Thanks in advance
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgdQY.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUP2m.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options you've entered are `true` by default, just remove them. [Here is the doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options)

Comment: Explicitly setting values to the same thing as their default should be fine... Is this (removing the options) fixing a different problem, namely running an older version of the driver/library that doesn't have those options yet?

Comment: No, as they say: "useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, useFindAndModify, and useCreateIndex are no longer supported options. Mongoose 6 always behaves as if useNewUrlParser, useUnifiedTopology, and useCreateIndex are true, and useFindAndModify is false. Please remove these options from your code." These were old options left in for I think backwards compatibility ("legacy options"), they just got around to removing them and making it work by default in v6.x.

Comment: Here is the change log if you're interested: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md